# Context Item Selected Error

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

i have a problem.
I am getting an error in my application. 
Context menu gives the following error when selected.

Favorites.Class

```
public class Favorites extends SherlockFragment {

ListView lv_favorites;
ArrayList<FavoritesItems> favorites_array;
ArrayAdapter<FavoritesItems> adapter;

public Favorites() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_favorites, container, false);
    return vi;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    init();
    loadListview();
    listViewListener();


}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    Utils.getDeleteFavoritesContextMenu(getSherlockActivity(), menu, v, menuInfo);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

        if(item.getTitle()==getResources().getString(R.string.delete_favorites)){

        }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}



private void listViewListener() {
    lv_favorites.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            FavoritesItems item = favorites_array.get(position);
            Utils.gotoNewspaper(getSherlockActivity(), item.getUrl(),item.getName());
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (outState != null) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}

private void init() {
    favorites_array = new ArrayList<FavoritesItems>();

    lv_favorites = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id._lv_favorites);
}

private void loadListview() {

    favorites_array = Utils.getFavorites(getSherlockActivity());
    adapter = new MyAdpater(getSherlockActivity());
    lv_favorites.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv_favorites);

}

public class MyAdpater extends ArrayAdapter<FavoritesItems> {
    private LayoutInflater inf;

    public MyAdpater(Context context) {
        super(getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.item_favorites, favorites_array);
        this.inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null) {
            vi = inf.inflate(R.layout.item_favorites, parent, false);
        }

        FavoritesItems item = favorites_array.get(position);

        TextView tv_name = (TextView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id._tv_item_favorites_newspapersname);
        tv_name.setText(item.getName());

        ImageView img_flag = (ImageView) vi
                .findViewById(R.id._img_item_favorites_flag);
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(img_flag, item.getFlag());
        return vi;
    }

}
```

}

Error

```
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209): Process: com.brnbykinc.worldnewspapers, PID: 2209
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.brnbykinc.worlnewspapers.Search.onContextItemSelected(Search.java:225)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:1623)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2015)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:381)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:210)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3864)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 07:46:50.810: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is my problem? Thanks for all ..

**EDIT: comments section **

```
public static void getAddFavoritesContextMenu(Context context, ContextMenu menu, View v, 
      ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { 
      String[] con_menu = context.getResources().getStringArray( R.array.context_menu); 
      int con_menu_length = context.getResources().getStringArray( R.array.context_menu).length; 
      // menu.setHeaderTitle(context.getResources().getString( // R.string.context_menu_title)); 
      /** i=0 info, i=1 add favorites **/ 
      for (int i = 0; i < con_menu_length; i++) { 
             menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, con_menu[i]); 
      }
}
```

Comment: `Invalid index 1, size is 0`. is your list populated. looks like its not

Comment: Invalid index is true, there is one item in context menu.

Comment: congrats @Raghunandan for  crossed 50k reputation.And Here list with no elements..

Comment: this is pupulate 'public static void getAddFavoritesContextMenu(Context context,
   ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

  String[] con_menu = context.getResources().getStringArray(
    R.array.context_menu);
  int con_menu_length = context.getResources().getStringArray(
    R.array.context_menu).length;
  // menu.setHeaderTitle(context.getResources().getString(
  // R.string.context_menu_title));

  /** i=0 info, i=1 add favorites **/

  for (int i = 0; i < con_menu_length; i++) {
   menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, con_menu[i]);
  }
 }'